# Is it possible to conceive concepts like a coordinate system in a completely empty space?

Tags: spacetime, coordinate-systems

I am very poor at English, so I used ChatGPT to translate my question.

My question is here (Is my idea right?):

Is it possible to conceive concepts like a coordinate system in a completely empty space?

I believe that without some reference, even establishing an origin becomes impossible.

In a space where there is just one object (please consider the object is very small), it is possible to consider an origin. You can regard the location of that object as the origin.

However, I think it's not possible to conceive axes in this context.

In a space with exactly two objects (please consider the objects are very small), it is possible to establish an origin and one axis. You can choose a location of one object as the origin and define an axis with a positive direction towards the other object's location.

Nevertheless, I believe it's not possible to conceive the other two axes.

It is only when there are three objects (please consider the objects are very small) in a space that one can begin to consider a coordinate system.

Comment: The idea you are thinking is correct, but the details are wrong. You are allowed to just lay down any coördinate system as you like, as long as they are not obviously internally inconsistent. What is impossible is to draw physically meaningful vectors. With one object, then you can have radial vectors (+rotations if we lose some symmetries). The fact that we can too easily write down physically meaningless vector fields in mathematical matrices language, is one of the reasons why physics studies tensors and it is so fruitful.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.

The kind of coordinate system you are describing is a *reference frame*. A reference frame is a kind of coordinate system for specifying the position, orientation, and scale of processes in a space. To define a physical reference frame of dimension $n$, one needs $n+1$ noncolinear reference points identified with physical events.

Coordinate systems other than reference frames do not need reference points. For example, the complex plane (2 dimensions) and the real number line (1 dimension) are coordinate systems, but they are not reference frames.

Comment: g s, thank you very much for your answer.